# What is the meaning of "figure-8 mission"؟

Tags: meaning

I'm just reading this short story titled "Alan Bean Plus Four" by Tom Hanks. The story is about four guys who want to travel to the moon. The writer has used the expression "figure-8 mission" in his story two times and I don't get its meaning. Does it refer to the Apollo 8 mission insignia which was like an 8 figure? Here are the excerpts from the story:

> According to him, in the mid-sixties the Soviets hoped to trump the
>   Apollo program with just such a figure-eight mission: no orbit, no
>   landing, just photos and crowing rights.
>
> I told Steve Wong that if he threw, say, a hammer with enough muscle,
>   said tool would make a five-hundred-thousand-mile figure eight, sail
>   around that very moon, and return to Earth like a boomerang, and
>   wasn’t that fascinating?

By the way I apologize if my question is off-topic. I read the help-center page but the information given there was not clear enough about asking such questions here.

Comment: figure of eight *or* figure eight 
*n* "**2.** (Aeronautics) a flight manoeuvre by an aircraft outlining a figure 8" TFD http://www.thefreedictionary.com/figure+of+eight

Comment: You should have made some special effort to print the question mark in mirror image. Nice! :)

Comment: "if my question is off-topic:" The minimum expected is that the asker makes some effort in finding an answer independently and shares their findings, so the potential answerers do not reduplicate the efforts. In plain English, that would be "Google it first. No luck? Tell us what you found."

Comment: This is not an English language question. Isn't there a "spaceflight" exchange site?

Answer (score 4):

The trajectory taken by the Apollo 8 flight resembles a figure 8.

[image: Translunar trajectory figure 8]

Jim Lovel, the command module pilot said this about the mission patch (shown below):

> "The design of the Apollo 8 patch was quite unique. Borman and I were in California working on our Apollo spacecraft when we got word that our mission had changed. We were going to take McDivitt's spacecraft and make a circumlunar flight around the moon.
>
> "On the way back to Houston the next evening, Frank was flying the airplane, and since I had nothing to do, I sort of sketched out what I thought would be an appropriate patch. After I returned to Houston I gave my sketches to the NASA artist who made the final drawing."

The mission patch is described this way (from [genedorr.com](http://genedorr.com/patches/Overview.html), a site dedicated to the mission patches for all US manned space missions prior to the space shuttle):

> The Apollo 8 patch is a lovely design. The general shape of the patch reflects the shape of the Apollo command Module, and is roughly the shape of "A" for Apollo. The red "8" denotes both the mission number, and the circumlunar trajectory of the mission.

[image]

Comment: Please see my comment at OP and the reference I cited there.

Comment: Usually, life is much simpler than we think it is.